# Terraform: Adding sensitive data to Azure KeyVault

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-keyvault

I am adding some sensitive data (for example password to existing sql server) to my Azure keyvault using Terraform. The problem is that this data are passed to Terraform in varaiables. I am using `sensitive=true` but still it can be readable in terraform file. The code will be stored in private Azure Devops repo but some other people will be able to see it. What is the best practice to keep it secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in my environment

By default, the values like key vault secrets are considered as **sensitive** by Terraform.

While running **terraform plan** command, you can see that key vault secret value as **(sensitive)**

But the problem is that these data can be seen in the **variables.tf** file. Whoever have the access to variables.tf file can see this sensitive data.

One way to fix this declaring the variable in the variables.tf without any default value.

Then while running **terraform plan** command, it will prompt to enter the key vault secret value and you can provide it.

However, entering values manually is time consuming and error prone.

Other way could be store these values in **.tfvars** file

But you need to limit the access of the **.tfvars** file

**Reference**: [Protect Sensitive Input Variables | Terraform - HashiCorp Learn](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/sensitive-variables)

Comment: I am storing these variables in tfvars. Limiting access to this file seems to be good idea. I thought about secure this somehow in terraform but I think it will be the easiest option. Thank you